# mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: hardware init failed

Tags: linux, boot, wifi, hardware

Wi-Fi doesn't work after boot. Reboot doesn't help.

```
nov 01 23:54:17 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 ->0002)
nov 01 23:54:17 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: ASIC revision: 79220010
nov 01 23:54:20 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 1) timeout
nov 01 23:54:23 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 2) timeout
nov 01 23:54:26 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 3) timeout
nov 01 23:54:30 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 4) timeout
nov 01 23:54:33 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 5) timeout
nov 01 23:54:36 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 6) timeout
nov 01 23:54:39 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 7) timeout
nov 01 23:54:42 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 8) timeout
nov 01 23:54:45 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 9) timeout
nov 01 23:54:48 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: Message 0004008a (seq 10) timeout
nov 01 23:54:49 fedora kernel: mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: hardware init failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MediaTek is known for its bugs. Check, that you are running kernel >= 5.18.

After this, you should unplug your pc from the outlet or turn of switch on the PSU. Then spam `turn on` button multiple times for several seconds to discharge capacitors on the motherboard.  Wi-Fi controller will reset its internal state and will start working after this.

Comment: had the issue with kernel 6.0.10, turned off the laptop for 5mins then it worked again

Comment: @A.Binzxxxxxx btw `6.1.0-0.rc7.51` doesn't have this issue at all

Comment: Problem still exists on my machine with mt9722 with 6.1.0.

Comment: Problem still exists on 6.1.6 on my laptop as well

Comment: i would have NEVER figured this out. thank you! just randomly started happening today with bluetooth. kernel 6.3.1, so still an issue

Comment: Problem still exists on 6.3.8 on my laptop with mt7921e. Since I cannot disconnect the battery I tried powering off the wifi with the built-in Fn button but it didn't work. I bought a USB-Wifi adapter in the meanwhile with more stable drivers.

Comment: I have a brand new asus scar laptop and the issue is present with any version of debian/ubuntu tested,  also the daily 23.10 ones
bug is also mentioned here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2006797
I tried multiple power resets, but I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Kernel 6.5 probably will finally have the issue fixed: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt7921?id=525c469e5de9bf7e53574396196e80fc716ac9eb