# No wifi adapter found ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, asus

I had to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 due to problems with an nvidia graphics driver, and now its not detecting the wifi adapter. I'm using an Asus ROG Strix G15 AMD Ryzen 7 6800H, nvidia geforce RTX 3050

`sudo lshw -C network` outputs the following:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 05
       serial: 50:eb:f6:d0:f8:1c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 ip=192.168.0.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fca00000-fca0ffff memory:fca10000-fca13fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=mt7921e latency=0
       resources: iomemory:ff0-fef irq:96 memory:ff20300000-ff203fffff memory:fc900000-fc907fff
```

and `lspci -nn` outputs the following:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b5] (rev 01)
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b6]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b7] (rev 01)
00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b8]
00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ba]
00:01.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ba]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b7] (rev 01)
00:02.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14ba]
00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b7] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b7] (rev 01)
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b7] (rev 01)
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b9] (rev 10)
00:08.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14b9] (rev 10)
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1679]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:167a]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:167b]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:167c]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:167d]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:167e]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:167f]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1680]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] [10de:25a2] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2291] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:5411] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7922]
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt [1002:1681] (rev c8)
05:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
05:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP [1022:1649]
05:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:161d]
05:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:161e]
05:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 60)
05:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
06:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:161f]
06:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15d6]
06:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15d7]
```

So its not even detecting it. Looking it up on the [asus website](https://rog.asus.com/ca-en/laptops/rog-strix/rog-strix-g15-2022-series/spec/) its supposed to be

Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) (Triple band) 2*2 + Bluetooth® 5.3 Wireless Card (*Bluetooth® version may change with OS version different.) -RangeBoost

I'm not sure if thats the card, but I don't know how to find that information through my system and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You have this device: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-0616-105b-e0cd Check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723828/mt7921e-00000900-0-hardware-init-failed or this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456981/ubuntu-22-10-mt7622-wireless-device-doesnt-work

Comment: sweet baby jesus. I can't believe spamming the power button worked. Thank you!

Comment: LOL really? OMG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723828/mt7921e-00000900-0-hardware-init-failed)
`uname -f` returned `5.19.0-43-generic`
so I unplugged the charger, turned off the machine, spammed the power button, waited 5 mins, turned it on, and bam there was wifi.

Now when i do `sudo lshw -C network` the second entry has changed to

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 34:6f:24:fc:cc:7b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.19.0-43-generic firmware=____000000-20220908203253 ip=192.168.0.28 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:ff0-fef irq:98 memory:ff20300000-ff203fffff memory:fc900000-fc907fff
```

and `lspci` now outputs

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b5 (rev 01)
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b6
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b8
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ba
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ba
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ba
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b9 (rev 10)
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b9 (rev 10)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1679
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167a
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167b
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167c
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167d
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167e
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167f
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1680
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2291 (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5411 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
04:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7922
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt (rev c8)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 161d
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 161e
05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 60)
05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
06:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 161f
06:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d6
06:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d7
```

which is largely similar but things like
`Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7922]`
have changed to
`Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7922`

If anyone knows why, drop a comment?